# Trying to animate backgroundcolor on a uilabel to achieve a 'fade' effect, but it applies instantly

Tags: iphone, objective-c, animation, uiview

I'm trying to animate backgroundcolor on a uilabel to achieve a 'fade' effect. My code looks like this:

```
UILabel *lbl = ...
UIColor *oldCol = lbl.backgroundColor;
lbl.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];
[UIView animateWithDuration:1.0 animations:^(void) {
    lbl.backgroundColor = oldCol;
}];
```

But it instantly reverts to the original colour. I also tried the below, to isolate the problem:

```
lbl.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];
[UIView animateWithDuration:1.0 animations:^(void) {
    lbl.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];
}];
```

And it instantly goes to green. Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Background color of UILabel isn't animatable. See [How to animate the background color of a UILabel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3762561/how-to-animate-the-background-color-of-a-uilabel) for a possible workaround.

Answer (score 0):

The `UILabel` background color itself isn't animatable, but the `UILabel` **layer** background color is. So don't set the main background color, otherwise it will hide the layer color. Just make the main background clear so that the layer shows through.

```
myLabel.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
```

If you need to set an initial color you can do it like this:

```
myLabel.layer.backgroundColor = UIColor.blueColor().CGColor
```

Then to animate this color to a new one you can do the following:

```
UIView.animateWithDuration(1.0, animations: {

    self.myLabel.layer.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor().CGColor
})
```

This answer is in Swift, but the idea is the same.