# How do I animate a UILabel's color?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, animation, uilabel

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to animate the background color of a UILabel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3762561/how-to-animate-the-background-color-of-a-uilabel)

I'm pretty new to animating things on iOS and have a basic question.

I have a UILabel that I want to briefly change the color of. Basically, inside of cellForRowAtIndexPath: I am reloading my cell's every 15 seconds or so. If a certain cell meet's a requirement, I want to briefly change the label's color and animate it to fade off back to it's original color.

Pop on, fade out.

Any tips would be amazing. Thanks guys.

Comment: You probably want to check out: 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3762561/how-to-animate-the-background-color-of-a-uilabel

Comment: Bum deal. I guess I'll have to find another solution. Thanks Totumus.

Comment: You might wanna try the NSTimer thing with 2 labels on top of eachother. You will figure it out ;) Its in the same question if i recall.

Answer (score 3):

This isn't the brightest solution, but it might get you to what you need: Create an identical, new UILabel with the same frame, font, etc... but with a different color. Use the animatable "alpha" property to fade your old color out and it will seem as if the underlaying label's color is being transitioned in.

Comment: Actually, this is a pretty good solution. Since we're not redrawing the label - just changing the alpha - it's going to be *fast* (much faster than a re-implementation of UILabel that actually redraws the text in a new colour).