# UILabel change background color gradually

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, uilabel, background-color

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to animate the background color of a UILabel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3762561/how-to-animate-the-background-color-of-a-uilabel)

Halle, I've an UILabel with a white background color, then I have a switch and when I switch on an action changes the background color to black.
Is there a mode to change gradually this color? I don't want change immediately the color but create an effect of switching off.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Core Animation or UIView animation.

```
//viewDidLoad

    //Initial Color of White
    label.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

    //Animate to black color over period of two seconds (changeable)
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:2];               //Change the "2" to the desired duration

    label.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];

    [UIView commitAnimations];
```

This code doesn't necessarily have to be in `viewDidLoad`. You could put it anywhere you want it to be called, but since this is a UIView animation and not a Core Animation animation, it cannot run at the same time as any other UIView animation.

Hope this helps!