# Animation finishes immediately, regardless of duration and delay

Tags: ios, swift, animation

I have this animation block, but the `cell` background color is `clear` immediately:

```
cell.mylabel.backgroundColor = .orange
UIView.animate(withDuration: 3.0, delay:3, animations: {
    cell.mylabel.backgroundColor = .clear
})
```

The point is I am running this in `cellForRowAt`

I tried moving animation to my custom cell, but no success again:

```
override func didMoveToWindow() {
            UIView.animate(withDuration: 3.0, delay:3, animations: {
                self.mylabel.backgroundColor = .clear
            })
    }
```

Comment: Do the animation in `tableView:willDisplayCell:forRowAtIndexPath:` instead of `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this,

```
cell.mylabel.layer.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor().CGColor
UIView.animate(withDuration: 3.0, delay:3, animations: {
    cell.mylabel.layer.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor().CGColor
})
```

Comment: Why change it to the layer?

Comment: I am not found animation for View background color. Yes of course we can use like -      (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
        ((RouteListCell *)cell).name.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        [((RouteListCell *)cell).name backgroundGlowAnimationFromColor:[UIColor whiteColor] toColor:[UIColor redColor] clearAnimationsFirst:YES];
}

Comment: @AVEbrahimi I found this answer from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3762561/how-to-animate-the-background-color-of-a-uilabel

Comment: @Sujit In the future, when you copy some one else's answer, you should include the proper reference in your answer. Otherwise it is plagiarism. Better yet, if you think another question is a duplicate, vote to close the question as a duplicate.

Comment: @rmaddy Thanks buddy. I will remember

Answer (score 2):

> The point is I am running this in `cellForRowAt`

That is too early, because the cell may not be in the on-screen view hierarchy yet. You can only animate a view that's in the on-screen view hierarchy. You need to find a way to add the animation after the cell has been added as a subview of the table view.

I would create a custom `UITableViewCell` subclass. In the subclass, I would override `didMoveToWindow` to add the animation to `self`.

Alternatively, it might work to override `viewDidLayoutSubviews` in the table view controller (if it has one), and add the animation in that method.

Comment: Using the `tableView:willDisplayCell:forRowAtIndexPath:` might work too.

Comment: tableView:willDisplayCell:forRowAtIndexPath did not work, too, :(