# UIView.animate does not work on background color

Tags: ios, swift, uiview

I have multiple labels with lightGray background color, and I want to animate their colors to UIColor.clear:

```
UIView.animate(withDuration: 5.0, animations: {
                    self.titleLabel.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
                    self.dateLabel.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
                    self.categoryLabel.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
                })
```

But color changes instantly! Why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I dont know the reason behind this why Apple didnt allow to animate the background color change, but here is a solution provided in another [stackoverflow's post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3762561/how-to-animate-the-background-color-of-a-uilabel), which is as follows:

```
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>

...

theLabel.layer.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor].CGColor;

[UIView animateWithDuration:2.0 animations:^{
    theLabel.layer.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor].CGColor;
} completion:NULL];
```

Another hack is that you make a `UIView` behind `UILabel`, and give `UILabel` clear color, this way you  can animate the color change of `UIView`

Comment: Is it Objective-c? :)

Comment: Yes, you need it in Swift?

Comment: Not me, @RankoR does, please recheck the question, the code snippet is Swift code and there is no objective-c tag. That's why I think it should be Swift. Thank you for the answer :)

Comment: It is just for reference :)

Comment: Thanks, translated this to Swift and it works!