# SceneKit: animation of SCNView background color happens instantly, not gradually

Tags: ios, animation, uiview, scenekit, scnnode

Animating the `backgroundColor` property of a `SCNView` happens instantly, instead of gradually over the specified duration.

Here's the code:

```
UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, animations: {
     self.sceneView.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor
})
```

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3762561/how-to-animate-the-background-color-of-a-uilabel) is similar, but its solutions didn't work. Specifically, setting the `backgroundColor` beforehand and animating against the `layer` property did not help.

How can you animate the `backgroundColor` of a `SCNView`?

Comment: For anyone reading here, note that the question is about a **scene view** but the answer below (2018 answer) is about a **scene**.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change the contents of the background material instead. This will give you full SCN Material powers over what the background is, and the ability to use SCN Actions to animate any changes you make.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/scenekit/scnscene/1523665-background

---

Better way, and what I'd suggest, is to use [CAAnimation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/quartzcore/caanimation?language=occ). From the docs:

> You can attach animations to Scene Kit objects that adopt the
>   [SCNAnimatable](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/scenekit/scnanimatable) protocol, including nodes, geometries, and materials.

---

Generally speaking, the [diffuse](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/scenekit/scnmaterial/1462589-diffuse) and [ambient](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/scenekit/scnmaterial/1462558-ambient) colours of a material will be the ones to change to make an appearance adjustment to a background material, depending on how you setup lighting.

Comment: How do you use SCNActions to change the background material (or color)? There's no colorize action (similar to the SpriteKit actions). Thanks for your help!

Comment: Change the values of variables being using to define a material. This way they'll animate the look of the material.

Comment: You bring up a good point, SceneKit should have a modular, visual programming environment for materials, like Unreal and every other 3D engine. That would make this fun, and not feel like using 3ds Max's material editor in 1999.

Comment: Thanks for your help! So use which SCNAction function? `class func customAction(duration: TimeInterval, action: (SCNNode, CGFloat) -> Void)`?

Comment: Yes, that. Or make the property SCNActionable and use a CA Animation.

Comment: OK, thanks. Never used `customAction` before, will dig around for examples online. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Have a look at this, I'd say it's better than custom actions: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/quartzcore/caanimation

Comment: thanks! but how would you use this to animate the background color of the scene?

Comment: Get a reference to the property of the background material that you want to animate as a variable. Then change its value as you desire/need.

Comment: Added links and quote to answer. Hope it helps. @Crashalot

Comment: Very glad to help. Hope you're doing well!!! Will be pestering you about explaining initialisation to me... soon. I'm dense as two (or three) bricks.

Comment: Hah, will try! Thanks again for your help!

Comment: I've also found that if you need to update the background color frequently (e.g. a changing sky color), performance is much better using the scene's background material rather than changing the scene view's background color property.