# Animate with duration behaving weirdly with UILabel

Tags: ios, swift, animation, uilabel

**EDIT**: I would actually like to animate the `textColor` property. I thought it would be the same solution as for `backgroundColor` but apparently not because `textColor` is not available in `layer`. I found the solution to this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3762561/how-to-animate-the-background-color-of-a-uilabel).

I'm trying to change the color of the background of a `UILabel` randomly every one second. The code I am using works fine on a regular view, but is iterating way too fast when I call it on the label. Its as though animate with duration is not taking any time on the label. Any idea why this is? I actually would like to change the label text color so that's why its important it works on the label.

```
colorChanges(v: lbl) // TOO FAST!
colorChanges(v: someView) // PERFECT
colorChanges(v: self.view) // PERFECT
```

**Animation Code**

```
func colorChanges(v: UIView) {
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 1.0, animations: {
        v.backgroundColor = UIColor(displayP3Red: CGFloat(arc4random()) / CGFloat(UInt32.max), green: CGFloat(arc4random()) / CGFloat(UInt32.max), blue: CGFloat(arc4random()) / CGFloat(UInt32.max), alpha: 1.0)
    }, completion: {
        (value: Bool) in
        self.colorChanges(v: v)
    })
}
```

**Weird Behavior**

[image]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3762561/how-to-animate-the-background-color-of-a-uilabel

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to animate the background color of a UILabel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3762561/how-to-animate-the-background-color-of-a-uilabel)

Comment: for some reason the `UILabel` animation complete instantly, you can trace the problem in this direction

Comment: Hi thank you for your replies! The other posts you guys linked provide a solution for changing the background color. Any idea how I might do this for the textColor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try below changed method:

```
func colorChanges(v: UIView) {
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 1.0, animations: {
            v.layer.backgroundColor = UIColor(displayP3Red: CGFloat(arc4random()) / CGFloat(UInt32.max), green: CGFloat(arc4random()) / CGFloat(UInt32.max), blue: CGFloat(arc4random()) / CGFloat(UInt32.max), alpha: 1.0).cgColor
        }, completion: { [weak self]
            (value: Bool) in
            self?.colorChanges(v: v)
        })
    }
```

Please, try updated answer for label textColor animation:

```
        UIView.transition(with: v, duration: 1.0, options:.transitionCrossDissolve, animations: {
            v.backgroundColor = UIColor(displayP3Red: CGFloat(arc4random()) / CGFloat(UInt32.max), green: CGFloat(arc4random()) / CGFloat(UInt32.max), blue: CGFloat(arc4random()) / CGFloat(UInt32.max), alpha: 1.0)

            if let label = v as? UILabel {
                label.textColor = UIColor(displayP3Red: CGFloat(arc4random()) / CGFloat(UInt32.max), green: CGFloat(arc4random()) / CGFloat(UInt32.max), blue: CGFloat(arc4random()) / CGFloat(UInt32.max), alpha: 1.0)
            }
        }) { [weak self] (success) in
            self?.colorChanges(v: v)
        }
```

Comment: Any idea how I can animate the textColor property? Don't think it's available in `layer`.